# Is $F$ continuous?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $f$ is the continuous function from $X^2$ to $I=[0,1]$
and $K$ is the compact subset of $X$. Define the function $F$ from $X$ to $I^K$ 
by $F(x)(b)=f(x,b)$. The topology on the space $I^K$ is compact-open topology.
Is $F$ continuous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theorem 3.4.1 of Engelking’s *General Topology* says that for every pair of topological spaces $X$ and $Y$, the compact-open topology on $Y^X$ is proper. Just before Proposition 2.6.11 he defines the notion of a *proper* topology on $Y^X$ as follows:

> A topology on $Y^X$ is *proper* if for every space $Z$ and any $f\in Y^{(Z\times X)}$, the function $F:Z\to Y^X$ defined by $\big(F(z)\big)(x)=f(z,x)$ is continuous.

Take his $X,Y,Z$ to be your $K,I,X$, respectively, and you have the desired result: your $F$ is continuous.

Comment: It has the same result on the topology of uniform convergence?

Comment: @John: Not in general, no. However, if $X$ is compact, the uniform and compact open topologies on $C(X,Y)$ coincide.

Comment: Brian Sir, you are right but I have one problem with your answer. Actually in Engelking $Y^X$ means space of all continuous functions form X to Y. But here $Y^X$ does not mean that.

Comment: $I^K$ denotes the function space here.